# Show that an integral domain $R$ is principal if and only if every submodule of a cyclic $R$-module is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

> Show that an integral domain $R$ is principal if and only if every submodule of a cyclic $R$-module is also cyclic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints.** If $M$ is a cyclic $R$-module, then $M\simeq R/I$, $I$ ideal of $R$. A submodule of $M$ corresponds to $J/I$, with $J$ an ideal of $R$ containing $I$. Use now that $R$ is a principal ideal domain.

For the converse consider the cyclic $R$-module $R$.

Comment: is it true that if T is a PID, then R/I is a PID, such that every ideal of R/I is an ideal? If not, I don't see how this proof works? I don't quite understand this proof. Can you explain more? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$R$ is a cyclic $R$-module, and so if every submodule, i.e ideal, is cyclic $R$ is a PID.

Vice-versa, if $R$ is a PID and $M$ a cyclic $R$-module, then $M = \langle m \rangle$ and so $$M \cong R/\operatorname{Ann}(m) $$ so every submodule of $M$ corresponds to a principal ideal $I \subseteq R$ with $\operatorname{Ann}(m) \subseteq I $ and so  is cyclic.

Comment: can you explain more about why why submodule of M corresponds to a principal ideal $I \subseteq R$ with $Ann(m)\subseteq I$ and so is cyclic? Thank you